# Unbounded array-based list output not showing up on display after reallocation?

Tags: java, arrays, stack

```
public class stackCode
{
    private String[] theStack; //the array-based stack  
    private int stackSize = 10; //the size of stack
    private int topOfStack; //top of stack

    public stackCode()
    {//this is building or initializing the stack within the stack 
        theStack = new String[stackSize]; //the elements within the stack 
        topOfStack = -1;
    }
    
    public void push(String elements)
    {
        if(topOfStack == theStack.length - 1)
        {
            int reallocateSize = (theStack.length) * 2;
            String [] newStack = new String[reallocateSize];
            System.arraycopy(theStack, 0, newStack, 0, theStack.length);
            theStack = newStack;
        }
        else{
            theStack[++topOfStack] = elements;
        }
    }

    public String pop()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Stack is empty, please fill in with new values.");
            return null;
        }
        return theStack[topOfStack--];
    }

     
    public void peek(int index)
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Stack is empty. No values to see");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(theStack[index]);
        }
    }
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return topOfStack == -1; 
    }
    public void print()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Stack is empty");
        }
        else {
            for(int i = topOfStack; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                System.out.println(theStack[i]);
            }
        }
    }



public static void main(String [] args)
{
    stackCode theFirstStack = new stackCode();
    theFirstStack.push("A");
    theFirstStack.push("B");
    theFirstStack.push("C");
    theFirstStack.push("D");
    theFirstStack.push("E");
    theFirstStack.push("F");
    theFirstStack.push("G");
    theFirstStack.push("H");
    theFirstStack.push("I");
    theFirstStack.push("J");
    theFirstStack.push("K");
    theFirstStack.push("L");
    theFirstStack.push("M");
    theFirstStack.print();
    
}

}
```

Hello! I am attempting to create an unbounded stack with an initial allocation size of 10 without using any library functions. I have set up the code where the allocation size doubles when the length of the stack equals the allocation size, but when I go to print out the whole stack for the output, all the elements are dsiplayed except for the 11th element ("K").

I tried playing with the constructor and the `push` function a bit. "K" does display when I change the `topOfStack == 0`, but I was taught that it should be initialized to -1 to indicate that the stack is empty initially. Could someone help to explain what I am doing wrong/if I am missing something? I am new to java and coding in general so I would greatly appreciate a reason behind the solution or behind the mistake I made. Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you just use a debugger and add a breakpoint when you are pushing K and another breakpoint while printing to figure out why it doesnt work as expected?

Comment: Note that if you resize, you currently don't add the element to the resized array.

Answer (score 0):

In your `push()` function you do not add the new element to the stack, when you need to resize the array. You just copy the current stack and forget about the new element, because the actual adding to the stack is contained in the `else` branch which is only executed when the `if` brachch isn't executed.

The simplest is probably, just to make the content of the `else` branch to be executed unconditionally.

```
public void push(String elements)
{
    if(topOfStack == theStack.length - 1)
    {
        int reallocateSize = (theStack.length) * 2;
        String [] newStack = new String[reallocateSize];
        System.arraycopy(theStack, 0, newStack, 0, theStack.length);
        theStack = newStack;
    }
    theStack[++topOfStack] = elements;
}
```